# Adding Bass Cut Switch on Pedal

Tags: switches

Is there a way that I could add a switch to a DIY guitar pedal that I'm building which would enable me to cut a bit of bass? I checked the web and all I can find are actual mods to the guitar itself. If anyone knows how this can be achieved, can they let me know (as easy to understand, please)

Any help that you can offer would be greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: The same circuit that goes in the guitar to cut the bass, would simply go in the pedal instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add a high-pass filter similar to the one that's in most guitars.
[image]
You'll see in this sample (thanks Google!) that they have a variable resistor VR1 that adjusts the amount of bass.  If this was a switch, when closed, you would have a straight feed and when open, the output would be have the bass filtered.  By changing values of C1, you would change the frequencies that are passed.

For your pedal, you could recreate this design, with a switches for VR1 (bass) and VR3 (treble).  You won't really need VR2 and C2 (volume).